# Problems with python script for logging to a file on windows

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new here...I tried running a python script for logging a message to a file....Here is the script

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log',level=logging.DEBUG)

logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')

logging.info('So should this')

logging.warning('And this, too')
```

I have this error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Python34\loggers.py", line 1, in <module>

    import logging

  File "C:\Python34\logging.py", line 2, in <module>

    logging.warning('Watch out!') # will print a message to the console

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'warning'
```

Comment: You need to create a [`logging.Logger`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/logging.html#logger-objects), and call e.g. `warning` on that; they are instance methods, not functions. Also, your traceback doesn't match your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot....I think i was able to resolve the problem...The issue is that the logging module I'm importing is not the name of the module I used for logging files.....Special Thanks bro...